# How to access config settings form within a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a security module that I put in my /lib folder in my rails3 application.

I may re-use this in other apps, so I don't want to hard-code url redirect values in the module.

How can I reference the config so I can pull settings from there?

Should I store config type settings in application.rb or is there another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put them in an initializer file specific to the module and not app.